# Inserting a linebreak in lines starting with a pattern

Tags: linux, unix, shell-script, text-editing

I have a huge file that has the following format:

```
#pair:  0   1   0   1   0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
#pair:  1   2   0   1   1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
#pair:  1   2   1   2   0   0   1
```

I would like to find each line that starts with "#pair:" and move the last 3 columns directly below this line.For example:

```
#pair:  1   2   1   2   0   0   1
```

changes to:

```
#pair:  1   2   1   2   
0   0   1
```

How can I do that with a command that works in Linux?

Comment: Are those separated by 3 spaces each, or tabs? Or is that irrelevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit verbose with awk:

```
awk '
    $1=="#pair:" {
        sep=""
        for (i=1; i<NF-2; i++) {
            printf "%s%s", sep, $i
            sep="\t"
        }
        print ""
        printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n", $(NF-2), $(NF-1), $NF
        next
    }
    1
' <<END
#pair:  0       1       2       3       4       5       6
0       0       1
#pair:  0       1       2       31      4       5       6
0       0       1
END
```

```
#pair:  0       1       2       3
4       5       6
0       0       1
#pair:  0       1       2       31
4       5       6
0       0       1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can tell `sed` to do that:

```
sed '/^#/ s/'$'\t''\([0-9]'$'\t''[0-9]'$'\t''[0-9]\)$/\n\1/'
     ^    ^    ^     ^                                ^ ^
     |    |    |     |                                | |
     |  replace|   digit                              | What was remembered
line starts   tab                                     | in the 1st \(...\)
with a #                                           newline
```